# Calc bottomline of valleys

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator, vectorization

Which way do I calculate bottomlines of valleys or even more preceise:
which way do I "find" valleys (for example suggested tectonic faults).

Sample below shows a height profile (profile from line) based on Aster
data and it's that I at most want to follow the larger valleys (long
arrowed lines).

I could go for hydrological methods (even though havent been working
with them), but using hydro plugins/tools a small breakthrough to lower areas would cause a runoff, while I want to follow the big valley.

Any ideas?

--- (edited)
To underline my problem, I've just taken a circa bottom line profile
of the valley pointed to by the most left arrow in pic-1 (arrow'ed).
The intersection is at about 8km of 1st diagramm (with arrows) and at
km 35 of second profile.

---- (edited)
Just to spread some ideas:
Rotating the 1st image arount the center between point 1 an 2 (1st and 2nd arrow, Height Profile) also shows "valleys" with different idth/height ratios, but still significant.

---

QGIS 1.8, Ubuntu, Aster Elev Data

[image: Profile-1]

First and second "sharp" valley from left (large arrows) are of most interesting to get the idea.
It might help to focus on focusing on strong beeing above/below average. Just an idea :-/

[image: Profile-2]

Comment: I don't understand the "small breakthrough" issue. Hydrological methods make a (crude) estimate of total runoff; you then identify the cells where that estimate exceeds a (rather large) threshold.  This eliminates all valleys whose total catchment is less than the threshold, leaving a network of apparent stream centerlines to delineate the largest valleys.

Comment: @whuber: Ref to the small breakthrough.... suggest simple some kind of terrace (your place to sit in the evening if owning a hillside home). If there would be a - in compare to whole surface - small hole within right in the middle at a slightly deeper location, the water would run off.... but netherless the terrace continues.

Sorry - I'm not a native english speaker, so sometimes I have to give very self-plaining visible and simple examples to explain my thoughts/ideas and intensions.

Comment: I do not follow your example. Do you, or do you not, want such a "small terrace" to be considered a "valley"? If you do, set the flow accumulation threshold low; if not, set the threshold higher.

Comment: @whuber - (skippinh hydrology) your ideas/thoughts are pretty difficult for me to translate; but if I did not get it totally wrong, you do pretty much understand my problem - any why I cant use hydrologic plugins/tools - and where I'm heading for!

Comment: @whuber - I'm searching the big terraces.
I do not want to follow the run off.

My english is awful, sadly, I do know  :-/ 

Say there would be a hole in the middle of Golden Gate Bridge covering 2-4 lanes (6 total if I recall my holiday some 20+ years ago) ---- I still want to go straigt on an not fell into the hole, following the bridge!

Comment: It sounds like you are not following valleys, or perhaps you are selecting a distinguished subset of them. A clearer description of what you mean by "valley" would help.

Comment: My valleys are tectonic faults.

Thought it might help to explain it a bit more "not too specific" explained.

Comment: How do you detect a fault on a DEM and distinguish it from other kinds of valleys?

Comment: Concret:
I'm trying to recalculate tectonic faults within the central asian orogenic belt (between Eurasia, Russian Creaton and Indian Plate), right inbetween the sayan fault and the Tunka Range, focused on Republic of Tyva at E095/N51.

Comment: Fair enough--but if you cannot supply a clear or quantitative criterion to identify the fault lines, you cannot reasonably expect us to provide algorithms--we need *something* to go on! One method people use is to post illustrations: consider showing us an actual DEM (perhaps in shaded relief) along with the results you would like to get from it.

Comment: @whuber. Even though most valleys are simply caused by tectonic reasons, I do additionally use bedrock kind- and age- maps, tectonic stress maps etc.


But I'm still a newbie, dont at all expect me to be an expert or even some kind of!


Do you recall my recent vectorizing thread?


It's intension was to be able to calculate - or give at least an chance/idea on - the rise and sink of tectonic sub-sections.

Comment: @whuber.

Gimme some days to formulate the citeria, if above wasnt straight enough :-/

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your graphs came from a R-script and that you are capable of using R. Here is a solution in R, which finds local maxima and minima along a data sequence

```
x <- rnorm(50,mean=1500,sd=800) # Example-Data
r <- rle(x) # Generate run sequence object

min <- which(rep(x = diff(sign(diff(c(-Inf, r$values, -Inf)))) == 2, 
                 times = r$lengths))
max <- which(rep(x = diff(sign(diff(c(-Inf, r$values, -Inf)))) == -2, 
                 times = r$lengths))
plot(x,type="l")
points(x[min]~min,pch=19,col="red") # Plots the minima points
points(x[max]~max,pch=19,col="blue") # Plots the maxima points
```

[image]

Comment: That identifies local minima of a single profile, but I believe the question asks to identify valleys within a two dimensional region: the profile was offered only as an illustration.

Comment: @Curlew: Sadly these are no R-Results, due to I learned /read knowledge of R would help me a lot :-/

Could you please point me to a suitable R newbie Documentation plus maybe an documented example
for local min/max calculations?

-> quick entry for local min/max calc.

Comment: @whuber: yes you are right. 

Profiles are circa 1st NE-SW, 2nd W-E

The "to calculate" line doesnt need to focus on 3D (height in the end is unnecessary), but simly show the 2D path of the valley.

Comment: Imagine a huge rotovator driving up and down on a random path through a mountain area.....

I want to follow it's path!

Comment: nah, sorry. Obviously i misunderstand your question (and i still do). Maybe instead of a straight line you could look for the local minima/maxima in a polygon (2D), where the z-axis equals the elevation. Sth. like this (http://tinyurl.com/cpxevju) ?